# Unusual behavior in java application deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, java-8, jvm

I have deployed a Spring 4 application to tomcat server which is hosted in Digital Ocean cloud, a CentOS VM. The application is a mobile backend application, mostly Rest APIs. JDK is openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b15, mixed mode), along with Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 and database is hosted in another VM.

The application is working as usual but sometimes there is an unusual behavior in the application.
I have logged every `REST Controller` call from frontend(i.e.Mobile) using Log4j and I use `tail -f /usr/share/tomcat/logs/someapp/info.log` to view the log in runtime. Frontend API calls are usually asynchronous and the server behavior is as expected. But when tested in some device,the behavior is weird. 
When the device makes API call, the log doesn't print the API call record, and also the response is also incorrect.
So I did remote debugging from Eclipse but it is very very slow(takes minutes to hit a breakpoint, don't know how to make fast), I have `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8090,server=y,suspend=n"` in `tomcat.conf`. Even while attaching debugger, the behavior is same, response is on the frontend but no log as well, also doesn't hit the breakpoint and incorrect data. But when same API is called from `Postman`, it is hit and also log is recorded and data is also correct. 
Frontend call is asynchronous and call multiple APIs at the same time.
I tried to replicate the behavior in my local machine but could not replicate, the behavior is as expected and response data is also correct.

But when single/(or less) call is done, the API call is recorded as expected, very weird.

Does JVM do some caching ? or it gives such behavior on multiple API calls at once ? Or some configuration is needed ?

Help, suggestions.. appreciated.

My Code :
Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get_VIP_requests/{fbId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> getVIPRequests(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,@PathVariable("fbId") Long fbId){
        try {
            HeaderDto headerDto = new HeaderDto();
            GeneralUtil.fillHeaderCredential(headers, headerDto, GeneralUtil.ACCESS_TOKEN);
            ServiceResponse serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse("Users have been retrieved successfully");
            serviceResponse.addParam("users",clientService.listVIPRequests(fbId));
            return new ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse>(serviceResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception e){
            GeneralUtil.logError(log, "Error Occurred while getting users", e);
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = ServiceResponse.generateRuntimeErrors(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        }
    }
```

Service :

```
@Override
    public List<UserEntity> listVIPRequests(Long vipFbId) throws Exception {

        List<UserEntity> requesterList = myVIPDao.listVIPRequestsNormal(vipFbId);

        List<UserEntity> blockedUsers = userFriendshipDao.listUsersByStatus(vipFbId, UserFriendshipStatus.BLOCKED);
        List<UserEntity> usersWhoHaveBlockedMe = userFriendshipDao.listUsersWhoHaveBlockedMe(vipFbId, UserFriendshipStatus.BLOCKED);
        requesterList.removeAll(blockedUsers);
        requesterList.removeAll(usersWhoHaveBlockedMe); 

        List<UserEntity> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (UserEntity user : requesterList) {
            UserEntity returnUser = new UserEntity();
            returnUser.setEntityId(user.getEntityId());
            returnUser.setFacebookId(user.getFacebookId());
            returnUser.setFullName(user.getFullName());
            returnUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            returnUser.setGender(user.getGender());
            returnUser.setPushNotificationStatus(null);
            returnUser.setProfileImageUrl(user.getProfileImageUrl());
            returnUser.setInfo(user.getInfo());
            responseList.add(returnUser);
        }

        List<BusinessEntity> businessRequesterList = myVIPDao.listVIPRequestsBusiness(vipFbId);

        if(businessRequesterList!=null & !businessRequesterList.isEmpty()){
            businessRequesterList.stream().forEach(b -> {
                UserEntity returnUser = new UserEntity();
                returnUser.setBusinessId(b.getEntityId());                    //To identify if the request is from business a/c or normal a/c                                                                  
                returnUser.setEntityId(b.getEntityId());
                returnUser.setFacebookId(b.getOwner().getFacebookId());
                returnUser.setFullName(b.getBusinessName());
                returnUser.setEmail(b.getWebUrl());
                returnUser.setGender(Gender.Male);
                returnUser.setPushNotificationStatus(null);
                returnUser.setProfileImageUrl(b.getProfileImage());
                returnUser.setInfo(b.getDescription());
                responseList.add(returnUser);
            });
        }
        return responseList;
    }
```

DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> listVIPRequestsNormal(Long vipFbId) throws Exception {

        Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyVipEntity.class, "v1");
        criteria.createAlias("v1.friend", "vip");
        criteria.createAlias("v1.organizer", "organizer");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("v1.requestStatus", VIPStatus.REQUESTED));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("vip.facebookId", vipFbId));  
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("v1.business"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("organizer"));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("organizer.fullName"));

        return (List<UserEntity>) criteria.list();
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<BusinessEntity> listVIPRequestsBusiness(Long vipFbId) throws Exception {

        Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyVipEntity.class, "v1");
        criteria.createAlias("v1.friend", "vip");
        criteria.createAlias("v1.business", "business");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("v1.requestStatus", VIPStatus.REQUESTED));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("vip.facebookId", vipFbId));  
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("v1.business"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("v1.business"));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("business.businessName"));

        return (List<BusinessEntity>) criteria.list();
    }
```

Comment: when you call from some other device and logs did not get printed , the response you receive is of same structure  ? is response changes or static response is coming every time ?

Comment: Yes, the logs did not get printed.And response structure is same but data is incorrect. Sometimes response changes and some time always same response.

Comment: restart your tomcat and than direct access from the device from which you are facing issue check if response is correct or incorrect

Comment: What kind of response do you expect to receive? What status code? What are the differences between response received on the device and the correct response? Are you sure that your code from the controller was invoked? 

It might be possible that your request from device is somehow different from the one which is sent from rest client and it is handled by some application filters without invoking the code from controller.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota The status code is 200 and I am not sure that the code from the controller was invoked or not, the only difference was that, the data was stale data, apart from that all data and response format are correct. The data that should be in the response is missing, I mean that there should be two array(just for example) blocks but only one array block is in response. But I can't replicate this issue in my local machine, I tried Postman, Web Browser, also I tried the device to connect to my local machine, it works fine. So weird.

Comment: @arjun I did restart and check it in debug mode too.

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you have code that's not running as expected, it helps to share the (simplified) code. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @OlafKock Ok , I will try to share simplified the code.

Comment: Can be there any other server, like testing or staging that can be specified somewhere in a configuration of this device.

Comment: @VDanyliuk This is the test server.

Comment: _"Does JVM do some caching?"_ No, but the client.

Comment: @zeroflagL Well, I have checked with the client too(android and iOS) but they said that they haven't implemented caching.

Comment: What kind of network are you using on your mobile devices to access your Java backend? Are there proxies in place or do you have a direct connection to your backend server? I can't imagine anything that would cause the described behavior other than some client/network caching.

Comment: @SudeepShakya, to rule out caching and usage of different server, could you try to stop your tomcat altogether and do the same test with the "bad" client? If the client doesn't fail on non-reachable server, you'll know that the issue is somewhere further. It makes sense first do a few tests when the server is alive (to let the hypotetical cache fill up) and only then shut it down and do a test again.

Comment: @dpr We have direct connection and also a HTTPS proxy. Does it matter ??

Comment: @SergGr I will try this one.

Comment: @SergGr@VDanyliuk and all, Hi guys, one thing I found is : 1) When I stop the hosted application(eg: app_abc), if multiple requests are done, the frontend gets the response, I mean if I hit once, no response, again and again hit gives the response. 2) If I stop the Tomcat, then no response even in multiple hit.

Comment: 1) I'm note sure I understand "if I hit once, no response, again and again hit gives the response.". Does it means that the first request fails but next several requests work?
2) The next obvious thing is to enable Access Logging in your Tomcat and see what requests actually hit it and what response is (see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve)

Comment: Are all the HTTP requests showing up in the access log?

Comment: @SergGr I mean that , 1) They hit the API, they don't get response. 2) They again hit, again no response. 3) But if they do they multiple times, they get the response. And I do have logs for the app, but not Access Logging in the Tomcat. I will try it.

Comment: @kevingreen Do you mean "access log" as "Tomcat Access Logging" or application log (I have used Log4j) ?

Comment: @SudeepShakya that's the one. Tomcat Access Logging.

Answer (score 2):

One probable cause can be `Cache-Control` header.

I believe, by default it is correctly set to `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate` which would direct the client application to not cache the request/response.

Quick way to check this is to verify the response headers.If Cache-Control response header is suggesting to cache the response, you can configure spring to change that behavior easily.

Here is a detailed article on Mozilla's website about this header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Hi, one thing I found is : 1) When I stop the hosted application(eg: app_abc), if multiple requests are done, the frontend gets the response, I mean if I hit once, no response, again and again hit gives the response. 2) If I stop the Tomcat, then no response even in multiple hit.

Comment: When you invoke your service via POSTMAN, do you get a Cache-Control header in response?

Comment: No, I don't get Cache-Control header in response. The response is `{
  "date": "Thu, 02 Mar 2017 02:39:31 GMT",
  "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
}`   But I have said the frontend to add Cache-Control header in request for no-cache.

Comment: Also one more thing, I have another application but Spring security version is "4.1.1.RELEASE"  and done no such other different configuration. It's response header is "{
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "date": "Thu, 02 Mar 2017 05:27:25 GMT",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  "x-frame-options": "DENY",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
  "expires": "0"
}" ,

Comment: So I changed the spring security version of the problem app too, now it gives these response header  '{
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "date": "Thu, 02 Mar 2017 05:26:52 GMT",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  "x-frame-options": "DENY",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
  "expires": "0"
}'.

Comment: But how does it changes the response header so much ? And just added ' <csrf disabled="true"/>' in spring security.xml. Can u please explain me ?

Comment: Spring security by default adds these headers unless explicitly told not to do so. I believe by adding it you triggered spring security's default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

are you expecting the data to be in the body or the header? you may be missing an @ResponseBody tag on your return.

Comment: The data is in the body as well as header too. And I have @ResponseBody tag. So that's not the problem. But thanks for reply.